# CSV File Remove empty cells / columns

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have a question which at first is very similar to many others but then I can't find a specific solution for it. I have a csv file with 10k contacts stored like this:

name, last name,,,,,description1,number1,description2,number2, until #10

Problem: the csv file has "empty columns" or empty cells for many contacts after the last number in the form of ",,"e.g:

Jon, Doe,,,,,desc1,number1,desc2,number2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Jane, Doe,,,,,desc1,number1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Julie, Doe,,,,,desc1,number1,desc2,number2,desc3,number3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

how can I quickly remove that for 10k contacts?

Comment: If it is a one-off, notepad++ could be a good option

Comment: If it's a one off you could use Find/Replace (Ctrl+H).  Find `,,`, replace with `,`.  Then keep hitting `Replace All` until Excel can't find any data to replace.

Comment: as @DarrenBartrup-Cook, it can also be done in excel. The advantage of notepad++ is that you can use regexp and replace ,+ with ,

Comment: I'm really going to have to look at Notepad++ a bit more.  I just use it for formatting my Access SQL for future reference (otherwise I have to spend ages removing unwanted brackets, table names, etc when looking at the query in Access).

Comment: can't use find/ replace because the commas are present between last name and first number description. Each contact has their row and each contact can have different number of phone numbers and descriptions...

Comment: Fixed it with https://www.exceltip.com/vba/remove-extra-commas-in-notepad-from-microsoft-excel.html